# PyTorch Linear layer input dimension mismatch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

Im getting this error when passing the input data to the Linear (Fully Connected Layer) in PyTorch:

```
matrices expected, got 4D, 2D tensors
```

I fully understand the problem since the input data has a shape (N,C,H,W) (from a Convolutional+MaxPool layer) where:

- N: Data Samples
- C: Channels of the data
- H,W: Height and Width

Nevertheless I was expecting PyTorch to do the "reshaping" of the data form:

- [ N , D1,...Dn] --> [ N, D] where D = D1*D2*....Dn

I try to reshape the Variable.data, but I've read that this approach is not recommended since the gradients will conserve the previous shape, and that in general you should not mutate a Variable.data shape.

I am pretty sure there is a simple solution that goes along with the framework, but i haven't find it.

Is there a good solution for this?

PD: The Fully connected layer has as input size the value C * H * W

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading some [Examples](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/mnist/main.py) I found the solution. here is how you do it without messing up the forward/backward pass flow:

```
(_, C, H, W) = x.data.size()
x = x.view( -1 , C * H * W)
```

Answer (score 5):

A more general solution (would work regardless of how many dimensions x has) is to take the product of all dimension sizes but the first one (the "batch size"):

```
n_features = np.prod(x.size()[1:])
x = x.view(-1, n_features)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is common to save the batch size and infer the other dimension in a flatten:

```py
batch_size = x.shape[0]
...
x = x.view(batch_size, -1)
```